# Oriented Object Programming value change with conditions

Tags: javascript, oop, if-statement, instance

Hi I begin learning Oriented Object Programming in JavaScript today.

I create an constructor object (if I understand => don't be hard I'm a beginner) called **Person** that take four arguments (*name, age, color, gender*) :

```
function person(name, age, color,gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.favColor = color;
    this.sex=gender
```

Then I have *new instances (2 instance to be precise)*, that are calling the *four parameters*.

```
let person1 = new person("John", 42, "green","m");
let person2 = new person("Amy", 21, "red","w")
```

At the end I made 1 sentence accessing the different properties/values of the person object for each instance with document.write() to output the result like this:

```
document.write(`<h3>${person1.name} is a ${person1.sex}, he is:${person1.age} years old and his favorite color is the "${person1.favColor.toUpperCase()}"</h3>`); 
document.write("<br>");
document.write(`<h3>${person2.name} is a ${person2.sex}, she is:${person2.age} years old and her favorite color is the "${person2.favColor.toUpperCase()}"</h3>`);
```

But the problem is, I wan't when the user is a woman to type just the the first letter of the word that is "w" and for a man the letter "m".

I made a condition in the object constructor but it doesn't works:

```
 if(person.sex=="w"){
        person.sex="woman"
    }
}
```

I don't know why the condition doesn't work, because it only output "w" instead of "woman".

Here the complete code:

```
function person(name, age, color,gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.favColor = color;
    this.sex=gender

    if(person.sex=="w"){
        person.sex="woman"
    }
    else if(person.sex=="m"){
        person.sex="man"
    }
}

let person1 = new person("John", 42, "green","m");
let person2 = new person("Amy", 21, "red","w");

document.write(`<h3>${person1.name} is a ${person1.sex}, he is:${person1.age} years old and his favorite color is the "${person1.favColor.toUpperCase()}"</h3>`); 
document.write("<br>");
document.write(`<h3>${person2.name} is a ${person2.sex}, she is:${person2.age} years old and her favorite color is the "${person2.favColor.toUpperCase()}"</h3>`);
```

And here the output:

[image]

==============

Comment: Use `this.sex` instead of `person.sex`.

Comment: Thank you bro, it's working now.

Comment: It's *Object-Oriented* Programming (as opposed to e.g. class-oriented programming), not about orienting objects :-P

Comment: When Im in the constructor I have to call it with the "this" keyword to reference a property of the current object that's it ?

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
function person(name, age, color, gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.favColor = color;
    this.sex= gender;

    if(this.sex ==="w"){
        this.sex = "woman";
    }
    else if(this.sex === "m"){
        this.sex = "man";
    }
}
```